# Paramiko slow ssh upload

Tags: python, performance, ssh, paramiko, transfer

I'm using the code below to upload a folder using Paramiko.
The folder contains 1200 (small) files and is about 40MB.
This takes almost 17s and blocks my app during the transfer ...

Any way to speed this up ?

```
class SFTP_Operations(paramiko.SFTPClient):
           def mkdir(self, path, mode=511, ignore_existing=False):
       
               try:
                   super(SFTP_Operations, self).mkdir(path, mode)
               except IOError:
                   if ignore_existing:
                       pass
                   else:
                       raise
       
       
           def put_dir(self, source, target):
      
       
               for item in os.listdir(source):
                   if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source, item)):
                       self.put(os.path.join(source, item), '%s/%s' % (target, item))
                   else:
                       self.mkdir('%s/%s' % (target, item), ignore_existing=True)
                       self.put_dir(os.path.join(source, item), '%s/%s' % (target, item))
```

---

```
def FullBackupSSH(self):

    destination_folder ="/.................."


    self.ssh_hostname = self.ui.inputSSHHost.text()
    self.ssh_username = self.ui.inputSSHUser.text()
    self.ssh_password = self.ui.inputSSHPassword.text()
    self.ssh_port = self.ui.inputSSHPort.text()
    self.ssh_commando = self.ui.inputSSHCommando.text()

    try:
        transport = paramiko.Transport((self.ssh_hostname, int(self.ssh_port)))
        transport.connect(username=self.ssh_username, password=self.ssh_password)
        sftp = SFTP_Operations.from_transport(transport)
        sftp.mkdir(destination_folder, ignore_existing=True)
        sftp.put_dir(source_folder, destination_folder)

        sftp.close()

    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
```

Comment: Assuming you have shell access, tar the directory on python, transfer through sftp, then untar through shell command.

Comment: Or open multiple connections. Uploading lot of small files over one connection is always inefficient. In any case, you should upload on a background thread, not on the GUI thread.

Comment: Hi Martheen , thx for your reply. I'll try the compression , do you have any example about adding threading to this ?